# Injecting JSON string directly to JSON object in RESTFUL

Tags: rest, jersey

I am implementing jersey restful web service to get JSON Object directly. For it i will pass a String (in Json format). Given below is the structure of class code i want to implement.

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public JSON putToJson(JSON todo)
{
    //*********


    return todo;
}
```

Please insist me how can i directly inject the JSON string into JSON object directly.

Thanks in advance.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding for your question:

Below code will inject the JSON string into JSONObject directly and you can access to that object

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public JSONObject putToJson(@FormParam("jsonString") JSONObject strJson) throws     JSONException {
{
    strJson.put("abc", "xyz");
    return strJson;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly, you need json runtime dependency, if you use maven, add this:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
<version>${jersey-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

secondly, annotate your vo with JAXB annotations

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class VO implements Serializable {
    @XmlElement
    private String id;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Then you can return the vo directly.

```
@PUT
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public VO putToJson(VO vo)
{
    //*********


    return vo;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply :)

I did it for DTO objects. But here i will pass the JSON string and i need to convert it to JSON object only. NO pre-defined DTO / Bean classes are there.